# Variable more than 1 URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to set more than 1 url variable in JavaScript.

I am preparing a  map, where only 1 url has been linied. I want to have more than 1.

I tried to use code like this:

```
var url = 'Peterborough.json';
var url = 'test.json';
```

but unfortunately only 2nd one is working. First one looks like switched off.

Does anyone knows how to place more than 1 url in the 1 line, to make them both working?

Thanks

Comment: A variable can only point to one value at a time.

Comment: What do you want to do with the URL's?

Comment: [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare two variables with the same name. You have two options here:

1- Simply renaming one of your variables, e.g.:

```
var url = 'Peterborough.json';
var url2 = 'test.json';
```

2- Use an array:

```
var urls = ["Peterborough.json", "test.json"];
//here urls[0] will be "Peterborough.json" (the first element of the array)
//and urls[1] will be "test.json"  (the second element of the array)
```

Answer (score 3):

A variable can have only one value at a certain time, what about using an array instead:

```
var url = ['Peterborough.json', 'text.json'];

console.log(url[0]);  // =>  'Peterborough.json'
console.log(url[1]);  // =>  'text.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var url0 = 'Peterborough.json';
var url1 = 'test.json'; 
console.log(url0);
console.log(url1);
```

I hoped it helped!